# Is Sufism considered as Islamic by other Muslims?

Tags: sharia, sufism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sufi Islam practice](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/41/sufi-islam-practice)

Do Sunni and/or Shi'a followers consider Sufi Muslims brothers in Islam?

> Sufism is a mystical-ascetic approach to Islam that seeks to find
>   divine love and knowledge through direct personal experience of God. 
>   By focusing on the more spiritual aspects of religion, Sufis strive to
>   obtain direct experience of God by making use of "intuitive and
>   emotional faculties" that one must be trained to use.  However, Sufism
>   has been criticized by the Salafi sect for what they see as an
>   unjustified religious innovation.  Many Sufi orders, or tariqas, can
>   be classified as either Sunni or Shi'a, but others classify themselves
>   simply as 'Sufi'.

Comment: Sufism is not a sect by itself.. Sufism is more of a _way_ of worshiping and living.. Any way most sufis are considered Sunnah.. correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: I added an answer to this question: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/41/sufi-islam-practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many groups that go under sufism some do not go out side of the Qur'an or Sunnah, but the majority do in one way or another and each of the groups have separate rulings in regards to them, and no one line can speak about all the groups.

Comment: +1 Thank you for this explanation.  I think I'm going to study more on Sufism and write a paper about it to my peers.

Comment: " Sufism does not go out side of the Qur'an or Sunnah" many examples of sufi sects to disapprove this

Comment: @UmarAdeel yes, and I probably should have mentioned that most of what is known as sufism today does lead out of Islam, and there are so many groups under that sects that each one has it's own ruling, and there are those who do follow Islam,. they are the Zuhhad which technically should not be called to Sufi, and that is what I am trying to talk about in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I previously analyzed Sufi belief [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/696/4). Quoting it:

> Sufis claim that Sufism is a way of purification. This claim of theirs also require existence of another claim in their mind, that is "*Islam itself is not enough for purification. So, we are making Islam better by adding it the way of Sufism.*".

Yes, Sufis don't find Islam able to clean enough, they develop new emotional methods that cleans better. The biggest mistake of a Sufi is that, when he cries out of emotion, he thinks that he became a good mumin. They consider the warm feelings inside them as iman (faith), but that's nothing but a normal hormonal phenomena which is similar to the feeling between a man and woman (not same of course).

Sufists live in [`tariqa`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tariqa) community. The leader of a tariqa is called [`shaykh`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaykh). People controlled by the shaykh are called [`darwish`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwish).

According to the rules of Sufism, a darwish in the hand of his shaykh must be like a dead corpse in the hands of corpse-cleaner. Some Sufists even say that, if shaykh orders his darwish to do something haram, he has to do it. According to the laws of Sufism, a darwish 
must obey to his shaykh under all conditions. This kind of shaykh-darwish relationship is nothing but [shirk](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/517/4). A muslim cannot be this much of obedient to any person even if it is the rasulullah Muhammad (pbuh).

Comment: I object to this line "even if it is the rasulullah Muhammad (pbuh)." ,by the way good answer , +1 for that

Comment: This is an old post, but recently brought up, and I downvoted it. Because rejecting Sufi's emotions by reducing them to hormonal/chemical activities is not a valid argument. Because nearly all spiritual phenomena (faith, worship, prayer, Divine love, etc) impact our internal biological functioning. So this can not be an argument for and against any particular religious emotion.